Morgan Generic Base XT board schematics
Where can I find the schematics of the Morgan Generic Base XT board with an 8088 CPU?

It might be helpful to add information about the board or at least some link.

If you know what the board looks like you could scroll through the 8088 motherboards on TULARC, there might be some information there.

From a few moments googling, the board appears to be known as a 'Zeta Peter-10'.  But that doesn't yield any more info.  Some guy is/was restoring a Morgan computer - or maybe that is the OP.

Are you referring to the motherboard from this question? (This doesn't appear to be the same motherboard as in Morgan's XT-compatibles, so I'm guessing not.)

I think the OP's question is clear enough in what it is asking, and is potentially answerable, though in practice it probably cannot be answered. Not every obscure clone has documentation that made its way to the internet.

Since most clones of the XT are just that, wouldn't the original version help you? If not, please [edit] your question to add the specific issue.
